# Sorting one list on the basis of other list values

Tags: c#, database, linq, sorting, collections

1. I have a table in database with columns:

   ```
   ID - string,
   Count - numeric
   ```
2. I have a list of IDs but they are of ID class(This list is a subset of the IDs saved in the Database.)

Now I want to sort the list 2 on the basis of the value of Count against that ID in database.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort entries in the database or extract some with an ordering? what type of database? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: Yes, I want to sort entries on the basis of the 'Count' value and I am using SQL server. But the Database contains many entries and I just need to sort the IDs that I have in list 2.

Answer (score 0):

It is achievable , in that case first you have to get the count of each Id in your list 2

```
           SELECT id from myTable WHERE Id in (id1 , id2 ,id2) order by count
```

In this case you have to pass your list 2 to the database.

Another way in case you do not want to pass the list to the database. Run a query to get the count of all the id in your code like this

```
          SELECT * from my table;
```

This will return the datatable , now loop through the id in your list 2 and then sort in the code.